# How to fixed the : if saz == eval: saz = eval(saz), I try to put this check system in my program for checking a void and it Error somehow

Tags: python, python-3.x

So now, I'm working on making a Surveying Calculator,but what I'm gonna asked here is not about the math or any survey. My problem is here I know where it is but I cannot figure this out...

This is what I'm think

```
if saz == int:
        saz = eval(saz)
```

I'm sure this is the bug, at first I use

```
if saz == eval:
        saz = eval(saz)
```

and it's still not work, it's not error and pop out but the code below that isn't working somehow...

```
def BAZ(self):

    self.ui.label_52.setText("")
    saz = self.ui.lineEdit_14.text()
    if saz == str(''):
        self.ui.label_44.setText("Incorrect")  # หาคำสั่งตรวจค่าเป็น int ไม่รับ text
        self.ui.lineEdit_8.setText("-=-=-=-=-=-")
    if saz == int:
        saz = eval(saz)
        if saz > 180:
            sbaz = saz - 180
            self.ui.lineEdit_8.setText(str(sbaz))
            self.ui.label_44.setText("- 180")
        if saz < 180:
            sbaz = saz + 180
            self.ui.lineEdit_8.setText(str(sbaz))
            self.ui.label_44.setText("+ 180")
        else:
            self.ui.label_44.setText("- 180")
```

Do you guy have any idea how to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if isinstance(saz, int):
    saz = eval(saz)
```

instead

Comment: you could also use if saz.type == int:

Comment: I have done that already,  if isinstance(saz, int):
    saz = eval(saz)    the saz in the last row was broken, it dosen't work

Comment: And what do you want this code to do (what is the expected output vs the output the code gives)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your answer lacks in quality regarding its **form**. Such input is very likely to be downvoted and closed. Thus: please use the [edit] link to improve your answer. Also, you should note that  *preview* window (together with the help explaining formatting) to improve the quality of your posting.

Comment: so the problem here is it's work (Not Error like pop out) but the code below that ( I have show up there) Didn't work... I want it to check, if that input is a number then the code below will work. that's all